# Jquery display array element in <span>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning jquery and I want to display the array elements in each span. Here is my function:

```
function display_locations() {
    $('document').ready(function () {

        array = ['london', 'ontario', 'san francisco', 'new york'];
        var newHTML = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            newHTML.push('<span>' + array[i] + '</span>');
        }
        $("places-panel").html(newHTML.join(""));

    });
}
```

In the HTML file i have:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery /1.4/jquery.min.js?ver=3.2.1'></script>
<div id="footer">
  <div id="places-panel">
    This will be replaced by new places from array<br>
  </div>
  <div id="button-display">
    <button onclick="display_locations();">Get places</button> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have the text replaced everytime i click the button (each of the element is wrapped by ). But somehow I think I get it wrong with the code so it doesn't work.

Can you please give me any hints on this?

Thank you

Comment: `$("places-panel")` -> `$("#places-panel")` and remove the DOM ready handler.

Comment: @JasonP post that as an answer before somebody just copies it :P

Comment: Eh, voted to close.. I consider that a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
function display_locations() {
   var array = ['london', 'ontario', 'san francisco', 'new york'];
   var newHTML = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      newHTML = newHTML + '<span>' + array[i] + '</span>';
   }
   $("#places-panel").html(newHTML);
}

$('button').click( function () {
   display_locations();
})
```

I turned the `newHTML` into a string because it is simpler to handle then the array, I also created the `<button>` `click` handler to do the requested change and finally also corrected the missed `#` for the place holder `id` (IDs are referenced with `#` plus the ID name, classes with a `.` plus the class name and HTML elements with just their name i.e. `$('button')`).

### Edit:

I had also removed the function `display_locations()` but I have just changed the code to leave the function to make the solution closer to the original request.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jWfLL/1/)